# Create struct from column vectors

Tags: matlab

I do not know how to create sturct variable in Maltab from column vectors. I have three column vectors, Voltage1 (32768x1 double), Voltage2 (32768x1 double) and Voltage3 (32768x1 double). I would like to create 1x1 struct variable with 3 fields (Voltage1-32768x1 double, Voltage2-32768x1 double and Voltage3-32768x1 double). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> a1 = ones(100,1);
>> a2 = ones(100,1);
>> a3 = ones(100,1);
>> b.a1 = a1;
>> b.a2 = a2;
>> b.a3 = a3;
>> b
```

b =

```
a1: [100x1 double]
a2: [100x1 double]
a3: [100x1 double]
```